# How do I use _com_ptr_t?

Tags: c++, com

Say I have a class that owns a `D3DDevice`:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    Thing()
    {
        D3D11CreateDevice(..., &device, ...);
    }
    ~Thing()
    {
        device->Release();
    }
private:
    ID3D11Device* device;
};
```

From what I understand, I can use `_com_ptr_t` to ensure that the object gets deleted without my having to explicitly call `Release()` in the destructor. The problem though is that I can't figure out the correct syntax for the template.

I could find hardly any information on `_com_ptr_t`, and the closest thing I could find to an answer was [this (Japanese) one](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nagoya313/20110924/1316877523). Following the syntax there, I get a bunch of compiler errors:

```
private:
    //ID3D11Device* device;
    _com_ptr_t <_com_IIID<ID3D11Device, &__uuidof(ID3D11Device)>> device;

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2065: 'device' : undeclared identifier
```

By the way, I can use this to return COM pointers from functions and ensure that they get deleted when they leave the caller's scope, right?

Comment: The documentation recommends using _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF

Comment: _com_ptr_t was really designed to work well with the #import directive.  Which won't work with DX, it doesn't have a type library.  Consider using the similar CComPtr<> instead.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any overhead with that? I understand it requires me to compile with ATL support, right?

Comment: Nothing comes for free, _com_ptr_t has overhead as well.  Don't sweat the small stuff.

Comment: @HansPassant ah, so long as it's not something ginormous like enabling CLR support, which would have me reworking some amounts of code.

Comment: No, you are just #including some C++ template classes, all pure C++.  Some compilers go catatonic with templates, not a MSVC problem.

Comment: Your welcome.  You got a good answer from Timo, good thing.

Comment: Earlier DirectX SDKs even had some #ifdefs that created _com_ptr_ts if comdef.h was included before d3d9.h, but that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are usually two ways of dealing with COM smart pointers that I would recommend:

1) You can #import the appropriate type library, which will auto generate smart pointer types based on _com_ptr_t.

2) You can use the CComPtr template to wrap your raw COM pointer in a smart pointer that takes care of the resource management via automatic AddRef/Release calls, but doesn't give you much else.

Because I'm a little lazy and normally I don't mind the implicit overhead of the wrapper auto-generated by `#import`, I usually use 1). One of the big benefits of using that approach is that the `#import` mechanism also generates function wrappers that make COM functions look more like normal functions with proper return types and a translation of the `HRESULT` to `_com_error` exception objects. IMHO that tends to improve the control flow in C++ COM code.

Answer (score 27):

_com_ptr_t is for defining a smart pointer type. For example let's define the IHTMLDocument3Ptr type:

```
typedef _com_ptr_t <_com_IIID<IHTMLDocument3, &__uuidof(IHTMLDocument3)>> IHTMLDocument3Ptr;
```

There is this simple macro for that:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IHTMLDocument3, IID_IHTMLDocument3);
```

This creates IHTMLDocument3Ptr, a smart pointer:

```
IHTMLDocument3Ptr htmlDocument3;
```

Using CComQIPtr this would be defined as:

```
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument3> htmlDocument3;
```

There is the "comdefsp.h" file with predefined smart pointers for many COM interfaces (https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/comdefsp.h). The "comdef.h" file includes it automatically. For example a smart pointer for IDispatch is already defined:

```
IDispatchPtr dispatch;
```

Using CComPtr this would would be defined as:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> dispatch;
```

### _com_ptr_t = no ATL

The advantage of using `_com_ptr_t` over `CComPtr/CComQIPtr` is that **you do not have to link to the ATL library**.

Other smart COM pointers that do not require the ATL library are `_bstr_t` (equivalent of `CComBSTR`) and `_variant_t` (equivalent of `CComVariant`).

Comment: > you do not have to link to the ATL library.
That is very detailed and what I was looking for.

Comment: `The link to "comdefsp.h" is broken, a valid one to Mingw should be [this one](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/comdefsp.h).

Answer (score 3):

The errors from the second code in your question mean that the compiler does not know one (or both) of the types before the `<`: you need to include the proper headers to ensure both `_com_ptr_t` and `_com_IIID` are valid and known types.  Also, the `>>` might be parsed as "shift-right" operator, put a space between them to allow proper, portable parsing

`comdef.h` should [fix both problems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362782/use-of-com-ptr-t-fails-to-compile-when-put-in-a-std-map-as-a-key) (see code listed)