# Releasing IDispatch pointer

Tags: visual-c++, com, ole

Quote from IUnknown->Release() documentation:
"Notes to Callers
Call this method when you no longer need to use an interface pointer. If you are writing a method that takes an in-out parameter, call Release on the pointer you are passing in before copying the out-value on top of it."

1.@rc variable is equal to 1 after calling pDocument->Release() in the code below. Should I call Release twice for pDocument?

2.In which cases refence count for IDispatch is increased?

3.Does reference count for IDispatch increase when I pass it to my function as a pointer?

4.I have tens of IDispatch* objects, so what if I forget to Release() any of them? Memory leak?

5.Is there any easy way to release all IDispatch* or I have to release them only manually?

```
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result.GetVARIANT(), pDocuments, TEXT("Close"), 1, saveChanges.GetVARIANT());

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result.GetVARIANT(), pWApp, TEXT("Quit"), 0);

//Finalizing
if (pWApp)
{
    pWApp->Release();
    pWApp = NULL;
}
if (pDocuments)
{
    ULONG rc = pDocuments->Release();
    pDocuments = NULL;
}
if (pActiveDocument)
{
    pActiveDocument->Release();
    pActiveDocument = NULL;
}
```

Comment: That the IUnknown::Release() function has a return value was a design mistake.  Useful for debugging but deadly when you use it in your code.  **Never** call Release() willy-nilly, that produces a hard crash when other code you don't know about has a reference as well and tries to use it after you killed the object.  Only ever call it when you obtained an interface pointer and no longer want to use it.

Comment: What does exactly mean "obtained an interface pointer?" From where? Still don't get.

Comment: From some function or method that returns one as an [out] parameter - e.g. `IUnknown::QueryInterface` or `CoCreateInstance`. Such a function always `AddRef`s the pointer before returning it, and the caller is responsible for `Release`ing it when done with it.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.@rc variable is equal to 1 after calling pDocument->Release() in the code below. Should I call Release twice for pDocument?

No. It means someone else also holds a reference to this object, and they wouldn't be amused if you get the object to delete itself right from under them.

> 2.In which cases refence count for IDispatch is increased?

When you call `AddRef` on it, or on any other interface pointer referring to the same object.

> 3.Does reference count for IDispatch increase when I pass it to my function as a pointer?

No, not automatically. The function, of course, is free to `AddRef` it, and would do so if needs to store the pointer somewhere so it could be used after the function returns.

> 4.I have tens of IDispatch* objects, so what if I forget to Release() any of them? Memory leak?

Yes. The same thing that happens when you forget to `free` something you've `malloc`ed, or `delete` something you've `new`ed, or `fclose` something that you've `fopen`ed.

> 5.Is there any easy way to release all IDispatch* or I have to release them only manually?

Look at smart pointers, e.g. `CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 5."Look at smart pointers, e.g. CComPtr or _com_ptr_t" - so is it useful when no type-library can be imported, and late-binding is used?

Comment: 2. Can you provide and example of "or on any other interface pointer referring to the same object."? Still not clear.

Comment: @UnhandledException If you already have IDispatch pointers in your code, using smart pointer for them is usefull, no needs of more type-library.

Comment: @manuell how can I use smart pointer for IDispatch? It's a bit complicated to start. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Declare a variable of type CComPtr<IDispatch> and pass the address of that variable to whatever function which wants an "out" IDispatch** parameter. Release will be automated when your variable leaves scope.

Comment: @manuell Documentation says that I need to include <atlbase.h> in order to use CComPtr. I don't want to use ATL or MFC. I use <comutil.h> for _bstr_t and _variant_t. Could you provide and example of using _com_ptr_t? just to replace this code: "IDispatch  *myDisp;" Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: I always use CComPtr, not _com_ptr_t. See "How do I use _com_ptr_t?" on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153873/how-do-i-use-com-ptr-t

Comment: `#import`-generated wrappers derive from `_com_ptr_t`. That's basically what the class was invented for. But you can use it standalone, without `#import`, if you are so inclined. For late binding, `CComDispatchDriver` is convenient (but, unfortunately, undocumented; you would have to look up its convenience methods in ATL headers). The main difference between `_com_ptr_t`-based smart pointers and `CComPtr`-based ones is that the latter report errors via `HRESULT` return value, and the former throw exceptions. You may choose which style of error handling you prefer.

Comment: COM objects often implement more than one interface. E.g. an object representing an HTML element may implement `IHTMLElement` and `IHTMLDOMNode` (and actually implements a dozen more). Formally, a reference count is per interface pointer: if you `AddRef`ed through some pointer `p`, you must call `Release` on `p`. Certain advanced techniques (e.g. tear-off interfaces) take advantage of this. But most of the time, an object has just one reference count; `AddRef` calls through any interface increment this count, and `Release` calls decrement it. Again, you should not rely on this.